# Javascript What is the best way to assure the value "true" in a ternary expression

Tags: javascript, jslint

I use jslint to check my javascript and I got a JSLint error which I can't find.
The expression is:

```
var foo = (bar === true ? true : false);
```

The Error is:

```
Expected '!!' and instead saw '?'.
```

The purpose of the expression is that I want the value of var to be the boolean true and not 1 or "not null" or any of the other "truthy" values.  only the value true will result in an assignment of true

What is the best way to express that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jslint is suggesting the following, as `x?true:false` is equvivalent to `!!x`:

```
var foo = !!(bar === true);
```

However you can simplify it more, as `===` always returns a boolean:

```
var foo = bar === true;
```

Comment: Thank you,  i was overthinking. It seems obvious now

Answer (score 2):

If `bar` is `true`, `bar === true` will evaluate to true. You don't need the ternary at all.